# How to add package to package.config in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I am fairly new to C# and using Nuget Package Manager. I am attempting to dynamically install packages at runtime within my code. So far, I have tried the following:

```
IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2");
string path = "../../../packages";
PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(repo, path);
packageManager.InstallPackage(package, false, true, true);
```

This helps me download the desired packages into the file system, but they don't appear to be properly referenced in Nuget Package Manager. I am wondering what should I do to have these packages properly referenced, thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to install a package at runtime? That seems fragile.

Comment: There is an article about your question here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f10a9c7e-4ad9-4fc5-be94-adfc2eb42a1a/install-a-nuget-package-programmatically?forum=vsx

Comment: @KennethK. Because I don't know beforehand which packages are needed. I am provided with a list of package names and dependencies.

Comment: @nycdanielp Thank you, that was a good resource. However I will need to use NuGet.Core so I don't think it will apply here